# Type Mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, worksheet, type-mismatch

I have the below code that is giving me Run Time Error 13, Type Mismatch on the line "If ws1.cells(i,13)="Yes" Then"
That column (Column M) contains either blank cells, or "Yes".
I've tried redefining "i" as String, and it didn't change anything.
Goal is that for every row with "Yes" in column M, that entire row is copied over to a second sheet named "Output".
Any help with this error would be much appreciated, also open to other ideas that may suit my goal.
Thanks!

```
  Sub Sadface()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trades")
  Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

  For i = 2 To ws1.Range("M65536").End(xlUp).Row
  If ws1.Cells(i, 13) = "Yes" Then
  ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
  End If
  Next i

  End Sub
```

Comment: Does `ws1.Cells(i, 13)` contains formula?

Comment: Try using `ws1.Cells(i, 13).Value` to make it perfectly clear to VBA that you want the value in that cell.

Comment: No, it is either blank (nothing), or contains "Yes"

Comment: Thanks Degustaf, but it continues to give me the same error message!

Comment: Try `If ws1.Range("M" & i) = "Yes" Then`

Comment: Thanks to you as well Maciej Los, unfortunately still the same message :(

Comment: can you try and declare i as an integer before using it

Comment: Thanks Pony2deer, same error though

Comment: You have an error somewhere in Trades!M:M. Go to the Trades worksheet and select all of column M. Tap F5 then click *Special*. Check *Formulas* and uncheck everything but *Errors*. Click OK. If you do not find an error repeat but check *Constants* instead of *Formulas*. If an error is found, clarify whether you want to skip it or remove it.

Comment: Jeeped you are awesome. It looks like the data I was using may have been a formula prior to me receiving it, and that there were #REF! errors in column M. Removing them solved the problem. You're the best!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have manually removed the errors from the external data. If bringing this data into your workbook is an operation that is repeated on a regular basis, you may wish to automate it.

```
Sub Happyface()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Trades")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

    With ws1.Columns(13)
        On Error Resume Next
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).ClearContents
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With ws1
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, 13) = "Yes" Then
                .Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

As much as I try to avoid the use of [On Error Resume Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx)¹, this is the most expedient method of dealing with the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) when you are not sure whether they exist or not.

¹<sub>The concept of breaking something just to see if it exists has always seemed just plain wrong to me.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Try with this, hope it helps

```
Sub justforyou()
x = 2
y = 2 'this will start the pasting process in the row 2, if you need to change it, you can change it
Sheets("Output").Select
Do While x <= 65536
    If Sheets("Trades").Cells(x, 13).Value = "Yes" Then
        Sheets("Trades").Rows(x).Copy
        Cells(y, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        y = y + 1
    End If
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: I don't think this will help.  [Based on the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604461/type-mismatch-error#comment49278442_30604461), OP had cells with errors in them.  Comparing an error against `"YES"` results in a Type Mismatch which would happen in this code as well.  Aside from that, an explanation of why you think this would work is more useful than code alone.

Comment: This could be improved if you evaluated `If IsError(Sheets("Trades").Cells(x, 13))` *before* evaluating `If Sheets("Trades").Cells(x, 13).Value = "Yes"`. See [IsError function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx).